# How to initialize with literals for generic type?

Tags: swift, initialization, swift-protocols

There are [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/initialization_with_literals) for achieving initialization with literals.

Examples: By using `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, we can do the following:

```
struct MyString: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    let value: String

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let str: MyString = "Hello World!" // It's the same as: `MyString(stringLiteral: "Hello World!")`
str.value // "Hello World!"
```

Also, by using `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, we can do the following:

```
struct MyInt: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let value: Int

    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let int: MyInt = 101 // It's the same as: `MyInt(integerLiteral: 101)`
int.value // 101
```

**My question is:**

How can we apply the same logic for a struct with a generic type? Consider I have the following struct:

```
struct MyCustom<T> {
    let value: T
}
```

What do I want to do is:

```
let custom1: MyCustom = "Hello World!"
custom1.value // "Hello World!"
// OR (since its generic)
let custom2: MyCustom = 101
custom1.value // 101
```

What is the appropriate protocol to conform to in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with conditional conformances:

```swift
extension MyCustom: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral, ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral where T: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: T.StringLiteralType) {
        self.value = T(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: T.UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
        self.value = T(unicodeScalarLiteral: value)
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: T.ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
        self.value = T(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: value)
    }
}

extension MyCustom: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral value: T.IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.value = T(integerLiteral: value)
    }
}
```

With that you can then do:

```swift
let custom1: MyCustom<String> = "Hello World!"
custom1.value // "Hello World!"
// OR (since its generic)
let custom2: MyCustom<Int> = 101
custom2.value // 101
```

For `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` you need to explicitly state and implement the inherited conformances, though.

Also, you need to tell Swift which generic type you want (`MyCustom<Int>` and `MyCustom<String>`) since there might be other types conforming to e.g. `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. For example the `MyCustom` type itself:

```swift
let custom3: MyCustom<MyCustom<Int>> = 101
custom3.value // MyCustom<Int>(value: 101)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean I have to conform to all protocols manually in this case?

Comment: @AhmadF The protocols are the same whether you have one generic struct or multiple concrete ones. So yes, you have to conform your generic struct to all `ExpressibleByXYZLiteral` protocol you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 1 protocol you could conform to, but you can create conditional conformances to all `ExpressibleByXLiteral` protocols based on the generic type of `T`.

```
extension MyCustom: ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral, ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral, ExpressibleByStringLiteral where T == String {
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    init(stringLiteral value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension MyCustom: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where T == Int {
    init(integerLiteral value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let myString: MyCustom<String> = "String"
let myInt: MyCustom<Int> = 21
```

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean I have to conform to all protocols manually in this case?

Comment: @AhmadF yes. As I've said in my answer, there's no 1 "ExpressibleByAllLiterals" protocol that you could conform to, so you need to do it 1-by-1 for all such protocols.